# Scheme: Avoid to invoke a procedure in order to grab a continuation?

Tags: recursion, lambda, scheme

So I had this code below :

```
(define escape
(lambda ()
   (set! halt (call/cc (lambda (k) k)))
   0))

(define multiply
 (lambda (l)
   (if (null? l)
      1
       (if (zero? (car l))
          (halt halt)
            (* (car l) (multiply (cdr l)))))))
```

and I had to redesign "multiply" to avoid "escape" and grab a value of the continuation,so that "halt" returns the value of the answer I come up with this solution how is it look?

```
(define multiply
(lambda () 
(let ((result (call/cc (lambda (k) (set! halt k) '())))) 
  (if (procedure? halt)
   (tester 
     ((multiply (lambda (k)
       (if (= k 0) (halt k) 
           (multiply (* k 1))))))
     (result 1))
   halt))))
```

Comment: Is `tester` a special form so that the `multiply` result is not applied as a procedure? What are you trying to do? The continuation `halt` would be the body of the `let`

Comment: @Sylwester my plans was having `tester` as a procedure that makes 'multiply' act recursively in the 'fail' case of the expression in the body of the `let`.Thus, if (halt 0) we can get out from `multiply` or causing termination if the "if" test returns that `result` is not a procedure or is 0. is it clear?

Comment: `multiply` seems strange as under tester it seems it takes a procedure as argument and return a procedure sine the parentheses around the result `((multiply ...)) ==> (multiply-returned-procedure) ==> some-value` but in the recursion `(* k 1)` does not evaluate to a procedure and `multiply` seems to take no arguments `(lambda () ...)`. You need to supply all the code referenced and tell how it should work and how it doesn't as I did not understand much of the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just trying to write an early-returning multiply function using `call/cc`?

```
(define multiply
    (lambda (l)
      (call/cc
        (lambda (k)
          (let loop ([l l])
            (cond
              [(null? l) 1]
              [(= 0 (car l)) (k 0)]
              [else (* (car l) (multiply (cdr l)))]))))))
```